# ANSI C: isprint() returns true for non-ASCII character?

Tags: c, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters, ansi-c

I have some C code that should print the entire contents of a file. The program previously prints a file just fine, but when it prints a second I keep seeing a Unicode character where there definitely should not be.

```
int c = fgetc(file);
putchar((!isprint(c) ? : c));
```

(wrapped in a `while(!feof(file))`)
Should only print ASCII printable characters, unless I'm mistaken. Regardless, the first thing it prints is `\357\277\275`, which isn't ASCII, and isn't printable.

The file contains only this: `foo+bar.foo+t-bar.foo+completely fake`

and it prints this: `�foo+bar.foo+t-bar.foo+completely fake` (with a newline between the strange character and the rest).

Simply printing it all (a la `putchar(c)`) puts the exact same character at the end of the line.

I've even tried using another file (by renaming the old and using a soft link to another), but I get the exact same results.

It also does this if the file is empty.

The file is completely plain text, created with vim, and there isn't anything special about it.

Here's the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *headp = "../include/header";
    char *listp = "../.piclist";
    FILE *head, *list;

    puts("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nExpires: 0\n");

    puts("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang='en'>\n<head>");
    puts("\t<title>Foo</title>");
    puts("\t<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/main.css' />");
    puts("\t<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/foo.css' />");
    puts("</head>\n<body>");

    head = fopen(headp, "r");
    if (errno) {
            perror("cannot open include/header");
            errno = 0;
    } else {
            while (!feof(head)) putchar(fgetc(head));
            putchar('\n');
    fclose(head);
    }

    list = fopen(listp, "r");
    if (errno) perror("cannot open .piclist");
    else {
    while (!feof(list)) {
            while (!feof(list)) {
                    int c = fgetc(list);
                    putchar((!isprint(c) ? : c));
            }
    }
    fclose(list);
    } /* else */

    fputs("\n<footer>\n\t<hr />\n\t<p>Copyright 2011-2012 the ", stdout);
    fputs("<a href='mailto:foo@example.com'> ", stdout);
    fputs("Foo Bar of Baz</a> of ", stdout);
    fputs("<a href='http://blah.org'>Blah United ", stdout);
    fputs("</a></p>\n</footer>\n</body>\n</html>\n",stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... also *when the file is empty*, because your feof() use is wrong. Please post the real code.

Comment: Could you show a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: putchar((!isprint(c) ? : c)); <- how does it even compile?

Comment: @H2C03 it's a GNU extension http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html

Comment: The "strange character" is U+FFFD, encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: What format is the file? What format is the display?
Using multibyte string (UTF-8, UTF-16) as singlebyte or vice versa is most common source of errors like yours. And yes, all that junk is surely printable (printable === not a control char)

Use hexeditor to investigate the file, it looks like BOM.
Most texteditors will process the BOM and present the file to you as "empty" while in fact it has 2-3 bytes added in front. (byte order mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DONT USE feof() (at least not the way you use it)

Also, your usage of errno is wrong. errno **only** contains a usable value after some operation indicated an error return (mostly by NULL, or -1 as a return value)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *headp = "../include/header";
    char *listp = "../.piclist";
    FILE *head, *list;
    int ch;

    puts("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nExpires: 0\n");

    puts("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang='en'>\n<head>");
    puts("\t<title>Warrenton Latin School | Gallery</title>");
    puts("\t<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/main.css' />");
    puts("\t<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/gallery.css' />");
    puts("</head>\n<body>");

    head = fopen(headp, "r");
    if (!head) {
            perror("cannot open include/header");
            errno = 0;
    } else {
        while (1) {
            ch = fgetc(head);
            if (ch == EOF) break;
            putchar(ch);
            }
        putchar('\n');
        fclose(head);
    }

    list = fopen(listp, "r");
    if (!list) perror("cannot open .piclist");
    else while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(list);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        putchar((!isprint(c) ? : c));
    }
    fclose(list);

    fputs("\n<footer>\n\t<hr />\n\t<p>Copyright 2011-2012 the ", stdout);
    fputs("<a href='mailto:warrentonlatinschool@gmail.com'> ", stdout);
    fputs("Warrenton Latin School</a> co-op of ", stdout);
    fputs("<a href='http://warrentonumc.org'>Warrenton United ", stdout);
    fputs("Methodist Church</a></p>\n</footer>\n</body>\n</html>\n",stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, my use of errno and perror has worked; although I've only tested that when the files weren't there.

Comment: feof() returns the error **after it occured**. In this case: after the last char has been read, fgetc() returns EOF on every subsequent call. You "consume" the first EOF (and consider it a valid character, and print it (it will probably become 0xff in the output file)) And only after that, feof() returns not zero.

Comment: I cleaned up the code to not use feof() like that, and now my problem is definitely fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I did not have the intention to solve your issue. I only fixed the obvious flaws ;-) Please note: the `if (ch == EOF) break;` is not very elegant (actually quite rude), but it was intended for educative purposes. (to avoid the confusing `while ((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF){}` which is more or less standard idiom, but might be a bit confusing to the beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring possible mistakes in your code `isprint()` considers all characters printable, except `0x00` - `0x1f` and `0x7f`.

Things like UTF BOM and other characters outside 7-bit ANSI can still be printed (despite the fact their meaning might change depending on the encoding).

Comment: Hm. Though using `if (c < 127 && c > 31) putchar(c);` had the exact same effect.

Comment: No, characters above 127 are still conisdered printable.

Comment: With the snipped from your comment it shouldn't print unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the 2nd operator of ?: empty, it equals to the result of the conditional. For non-printable characters, isprintc(c) returns 0, therefore the conditional part of the trenary operator is !0 which equals to 1. Therefore putchar attempts to print an invalid ASCII character and breaks.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be legal to have an empty string constant there, or is there something else I should do for that effect?

Comment: Move the conditional outside: `if(!condition) putchar(...);` You can't define an empty character (`''`) and `\0` (or the first element of an empty string; mind the data types) would output `\0`.